# Site keeps loading

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, performance, iis-7.5

My site is hosted in IIS v7.5. Coded in asp.net environment and back end SQL server 2012. 
It was working properly till today morning. 
We fixed some bugs and replaced the files in the server with latest ones.

We noticed somewhere in the site navigation, page keeps loading.
When site accessed from the same server machine, it works fine. 
After 1 hr of this we again find the same issue. we tried in different areas to find the actual issue like memory, code (we also reverted the last changes and monitored, issue was still there), IIS logs, code logs etc, but couldn't find any cause for this.
I know this is very little information. Please help with your suggestions and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear all your cookies and delete your browser history. Restart your server. The error is still there.. Kindly put the code and screen shots. That will be easy to identify the bugs.

Comment: @Pramod Any Updation in IIS Server?? or Any Changes in navigation code??. check the code once again.. We are not able to help you without viewing the code.. Sorry..